# SharePoint list item: Copy list-item-level permissions from one item to another

Tags: javascript, inheritance, sharepoint, permissions, workflow

I’m running into the following scenario, which I am unsure how to tackle.

I need to be able to copy the list-item-level permissions from one list item to another one in a separate list.  In other words:

List A contains an item named **itemA**.  List B contains an item named **itemB**.  I want to duplicate the item-level permissons of itemA into itemB.

Does anyone know a way to do this? This can  be with front-end code using JSOM, or with a workflow (2010 or 2013).

Things I've already tried:

- The "Inherit parent permissions" workflow action.  However, I want to inherit the workflow permissions from another list item, not from the list itself.
- My scenario is similar to this one: [Inheriting list item permissions via permissions on lookup field item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922015/inheriting-list-item-permissions-via-permissions-on-lookup-field-item).  Except I don't have the ability to build event-receivers so I'm looking for a JSOM or workflow solution.

Answer (score 1):

The following example shows how to copy list item permissions via `SharePoint JSOM API`:

> Prerequisites:
>
> Unique permissions should be assigned for source and target list items

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext',
function(){
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var sourceListItem = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("InTasks").getItemById(1);
    var targetListItem = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("OutTasks").getItemById(1);
    copyListItemPermissions(sourceListItem,targetListItem,
       function(){
         console.log("Done");
       },
       function(sender,args){
         console.log(args.get_message());
       }
    );
});
```

where

```
function copyListItemPermissions(sourceListItem,targetListItem,success,error)
{
    var ctx = targetListItem.get_context();
    var sourceItemPermissions = sourceListItem.get_roleAssignments();
    var targetItemPermissions = targetListItem.get_roleAssignments();
    ctx.load(sourceItemPermissions,'Include(Member)');
    ctx.load(targetItemPermissions,'Include(Member)');
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
       function(){

           targetItemPermissions.get_data().forEach(function(targetAssignment){
              targetAssignment.deleteObject();
           });

           sourceItemPermissions.get_data().forEach(function(sourceAssignment){
               var principal = sourceAssignment.get_member();
               if(principal.get_principalType() == 1)
                   targetItemPermissions.add(principal,sourceAssignment.get_roleDefinitionBindings());
               else if (principal.get_principalType() == 8){
                   var group = ctx.get_web().get_siteGroups().getById(principal.get_id());
                   targetItemPermissions.add(group,sourceAssignment.get_roleDefinitionBindings());
               }    
           });
           targetListItem.update();
           ctx.executeQueryAsync(
               function(){
                  success();       
               },
               error   
           );             
       },
       error   
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you much! This almost seems to do the trick.  However, I do get this JavaScript error when attempting the code:

`Can not find the principal with id: 11.`

Any ideas?